# Do not display axis in chart

Tags: php, phpexcel

Is there any option in PHPExcel to hide the primary vertical and horizontal axis in excel's **line chart**?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found the solution by made changes in code.

File path: PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Chart/Axis.php

Code change: `'axis_labels' => 'none'`

Thanks.

**
As of 1.8.1 or maybe even earlier you can style the x and y axes with [`setAxisOptionsProperties`](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/source-class-PHPExcel_Chart_Axis.html#175), like so:

```
$xAxisStyle = new PHPExcel_Chart_Axis();
$xAxisStyle->setAxisOptionsProperties('none', null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

$yAxisStyle = new PHPExcel_Chart_Axis();
$yAxisStyle->setAxisOptionsProperties('none', null, null, null, null, null, null, null);    

$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'Chart1',   // name
    $title,     // title displayed on chart
    $legend,    // legend
    $pa,        // plotArea
    true,       // plotVisibleOnly
    0,          // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,       // xAxisLabel
    NULL,       // yAxisLabel
    $xAxisStyle,// X-axis styling vertical
    $yAxisStyle //Y-axis style horizontal
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this,

```
$chart2 = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart2',       // name
    $title,     // title
    NULL,       // legend
    $plotarea2,     // plotArea
    true,           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,              // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,           // xAxisLabel
    NULL    // yAxisLabel
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already tried this one. But it won't remove the X and Y Axis values as shown in above picture.